# Dissapear JButton when click JButton

Tags: eclipse, image, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton

I've got an application with some JButtons, if you click them you see a image. Now if you open the frame and you dont have clicked yet you see a image in the middle of the screen. Now i want if you click the JButton for the image, the image is shown and the other image in the middle of the screen is gone but i dont know how to do.

My Frame:

```
package View;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


import Controller.HomeController;
import Controller.SelectieController;

public class Selectie extends JFrame{

    private static String Gregory = "Gregory";
    private static String Vermeer = "Vermeer";
    private static String Alderweireld = "Alderweireld";
    private static String Vertonghen = "Vertonghen";
    private static String Anita = "Anita";
    private static String Enoh = "Enoh";
    private static String Sulejmani = "Sulejmani";
    private static String Cristian = "Cristian";
    private static String Kolbeinn = "Kolbeinn";
    private static String Siem = "Siem";
    private static String Lorenzo = "Lorenzo";
    private static String Andre = "Andre";
    private static String Nicolai = "Nicolai";
    private static String Theo = "Theo";
    private static String Daley = "Daley";
    private static String Nicolas = "Nicolas";
    private static String Dmitri = "Dmitri";
    private static String Kruis = "Kruis";

    private JLabel label, label1, label2;
    private JButton keeper, verdediger, verdediger1, verdediger2, verdediger3, verdediger4;
    private JButton middenvelder, middenvelder1, aanvaller, aanvaller1, middenvelder2;
    private JButton aanvaller2, verdediger5, middenvelder3, verdediger6, middenvelder4;
    private JButton aanvaller3, kruis;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Container window = getContentPane();

    public Selectie()
    {
        initGUI();

    }

    public void initGUI()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle();
        setSize(800,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label = new JLabel();       
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 266, 800);
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        window.add(label);

        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setBounds(266, 0, 266, 800);
        label1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        label1.setOpaque(true);
        window.add(label1);

        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setBounds(532, 0, 266, 800);
        label2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label2.setOpaque(true);
        window.add(label2);

        JLabel foto = new JLabel();
        label1.add(foto);

        kruis = new JButton(new ImageIcon("../Ajax/src/img/logotje.gif"));
        kruis.setBorderPainted(false);
        kruis.setBounds(40, 150, 188, 188);
        kruis.setActionCommand(Kruis);
        label1.add(kruis);

        keeper = new JButton("1. "+""+" Kenneth Vermeer");
        Cursor cur = keeper.getCursor();
        keeper.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        keeper.setBounds(20, 50, 186, 12);
        keeper.setFocusable(false);
        keeper.setBorderPainted(false);
        keeper.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        keeper.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        keeper.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        keeper.setActionCommand(Vermeer);
        label.add(keeper);

        verdediger = new JButton("2. "+""+" Gregory van der Wiel");
        Cursor cur1 = verdediger.getCursor();
        verdediger.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger.setBounds(20, 70, 215, 17);
        verdediger.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger.setActionCommand(Gregory);
        label.add(verdediger);

        verdediger1 = new JButton("3. "+""+" Toby Alderweireld");
        Cursor cur2 = verdediger1.getCursor();
        verdediger1.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger1.setBounds(20, 95, 188, 17);
        verdediger1.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger1.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger1.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger1.setActionCommand(Alderweireld);
        label.add(verdediger1);

        verdediger2 = new JButton("4. "+""+" Jan Vertonghen");
        Cursor cur3 = verdediger2.getCursor();
        verdediger2.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger2.setBounds(20, 120, 174, 17);
        verdediger2.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger2.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger2.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger2.setActionCommand(Vertonghen);
        label.add(verdediger2);

        verdediger3 = new JButton("5. "+""+" Vurnon Anita");
        Cursor cur4 = verdediger3.getCursor();
        verdediger3.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger3.setBounds(20, 145, 153, 12);
        verdediger3.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger3.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger3.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger3.setActionCommand(Anita);
        label.add(verdediger3);

        middenvelder = new JButton("6. "+""+" Eyong Enoh");
        Cursor cur5 = middenvelder.getCursor();
        middenvelder.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        middenvelder.setBounds(20, 170, 148, 17);
        middenvelder.setFocusable(false);
        middenvelder.setBorderPainted(false);
        middenvelder.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        middenvelder.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        middenvelder.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        middenvelder.setActionCommand(Enoh);
        label.add(middenvelder);

        aanvaller = new JButton("7. "+""+" Miralem Sulejmani");
        Cursor cur6 = aanvaller.getCursor();
        aanvaller.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        aanvaller.setBounds(20, 195, 190, 17);
        aanvaller.setFocusable(false);
        aanvaller.setBorderPainted(false);
        aanvaller.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        aanvaller.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        aanvaller.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        aanvaller.setActionCommand(Sulejmani);
        label.add(aanvaller);

        middenvelder1 = new JButton("8. "+""+" Cristian Eriksen");
        Cursor cur7 = middenvelder1.getCursor();
        middenvelder1.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        middenvelder1.setBounds(20, 220, 174, 12);
        middenvelder1.setFocusable(false);
        middenvelder1.setBorderPainted(false);
        middenvelder1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        middenvelder1.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        middenvelder1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        middenvelder1.setActionCommand(Cristian);
        label.add(middenvelder1);

        aanvaller1 = new JButton("9. "+""+" Kolbeinn Sightórsson");
        Cursor cur8 = aanvaller1.getCursor();
        aanvaller1.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        aanvaller1.setBounds(20, 245, 212, 17);
        aanvaller1.setFocusable(false);
        aanvaller1.setBorderPainted(false);
        aanvaller1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        aanvaller1.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        aanvaller1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        aanvaller1.setActionCommand(Kolbeinn);
        label.add(aanvaller1);

        middenvelder2 = new JButton("10. "+""+" Siem de Jong");
        Cursor cur9 = middenvelder2.getCursor();
        middenvelder2.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        middenvelder2.setBounds(20, 270, 168, 17);
        middenvelder2.setFocusable(false);
        middenvelder2.setBorderPainted(false);
        middenvelder2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        middenvelder2.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        middenvelder2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        middenvelder2.setActionCommand(Siem);
        label.add(middenvelder2);

        aanvaller2 = new JButton("11. "+""+" Lorenzo Ebecilio");
        Cursor cur10 = aanvaller2.getCursor();
        aanvaller2.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        aanvaller2.setBounds(20, 295, 189, 12);
        aanvaller2.setFocusable(false);
        aanvaller2.setBorderPainted(false);
        aanvaller2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        aanvaller2.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        aanvaller2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        aanvaller2.setActionCommand(Lorenzo);
        label.add(aanvaller2);

        verdediger4 = new JButton("13. "+""+" André Ooijer");
        Cursor cur11 = verdediger4.getCursor();
        verdediger4.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger4.setBounds(20, 320, 159, 17);
        verdediger4.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger4.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger4.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger4.setActionCommand(Andre);
        label.add(verdediger4);

        verdediger5 = new JButton("15. "+""+" Nicolai Boilesen");
        Cursor cur12 = verdediger5.getCursor();
        verdediger5.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger5.setBounds(20, 345, 183, 12);
        verdediger5.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger5.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger5.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger5.setActionCommand(Nicolai);
        label.add(verdediger5);

        middenvelder3 = new JButton("16. "+""+" Theo Janssen");
        Cursor cur13 = middenvelder3.getCursor();
        middenvelder3.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        middenvelder3.setBounds(20, 370, 169, 12);
        middenvelder3.setFocusable(false);
        middenvelder3.setBorderPainted(false);
        middenvelder3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        middenvelder3.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        middenvelder3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        middenvelder3.setActionCommand(Theo);
        label.add(middenvelder3);

        verdediger6 = new JButton("17. "+""+" Daley Blind");
        Cursor cur14 = verdediger6.getCursor();
        verdediger6.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger6.setBounds(20, 395, 150, 17);
        verdediger6.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger6.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger6.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger6.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger6.setActionCommand(Daley);
        label.add(verdediger6);

        middenvelder4 = new JButton("18. "+""+" Nicolás Lodeiro");
        Cursor cur15 = middenvelder4.getCursor();
        middenvelder4.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        middenvelder4.setBounds(20, 420, 180, 12);
        middenvelder4.setFocusable(false);
        middenvelder4.setBorderPainted(false);
        middenvelder4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        middenvelder4.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        middenvelder4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        middenvelder4.setActionCommand(Nicolas);
        label.add(middenvelder4);

        aanvaller3 = new JButton("19. "+""+" Dmitri Bulykin");
        Cursor cur16 = aanvaller3.getCursor();
        aanvaller3.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        aanvaller3.setBounds(20, 445, 168, 17);
        aanvaller3.setFocusable(false);
        aanvaller3.setBorderPainted(false);
        aanvaller3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        aanvaller3.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        aanvaller3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        aanvaller3.setActionCommand(Dmitri);
        label.add(aanvaller3);

        SelectieController s1 = new SelectieController(keeper, foto, verdediger, verdediger1, verdediger2,
                verdediger3, middenvelder, aanvaller, middenvelder1, aanvaller1, middenvelder2, aanvaller2,
                verdediger4, verdediger5, middenvelder3, verdediger6, middenvelder4, aanvaller3, kruis);

        keeper.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger1.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger2.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger3.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger4.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger5.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger6.addActionListener(s1);
        middenvelder.addActionListener(s1);
        aanvaller.addActionListener(s1);
        middenvelder1.addActionListener(s1);
        aanvaller1.addActionListener(s1);
        middenvelder2.addActionListener(s1);
        aanvaller2.addActionListener(s1);
        middenvelder3.addActionListener(s1);
        middenvelder4.addActionListener(s1);
        aanvaller3.addActionListener(s1);
        }

}
```

Kruis is the image in the midd of the screen a=

ActionPerformed class:

```
package Controller;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SelectieController implements ActionListener {


    private JButton keeper, verdediger, verdediger1, verdediger2, verdediger3;
    private JButton middenvelder, aanvaller, middenvelder1, aanvaller1, middenvelder2;
    private JButton aanvaller2, verdediger4, verdediger5, middenvelder3, verdediger6;
    private JButton middenvelder4, aanvaller3, kruis;
    private ImageIcon imageIcon, imageIcon1, imageIcon2, imageIcon3, imageIcon4, imageIcon5;
    private ImageIcon imageIcon6, imageIcon7, imageIcon8, imageIcon9, imageIcon10, imageIcon11;
    private ImageIcon imageIcon12, imageIcon13, imageIcon14, imageIcon15, imageIcon16;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private Image image, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9;
    private Image image10, image11, image12, image13, image14, image15, image16;
    private static String Vermeer = "Vermeer";
    private static String Gregory = "Gregory";
    private static String Alderweireld = "Alderweireld";
    private static String Vertonghen = "Vertonghen";
    private static String Anita = "Anita";
    private static String Enoh = "Enoh";
    private static String Sulejmani = "Sulejmani";
    private static String Cristian = "Cristian";
    private static String Kolbeinn = "Kolbeinn";
    private static String Siem = "Siem";
    private static String Lorenzo = "Lorenzo";
    private static String Andre = "Andre";
    private static String Nicolai = "Nicolai";
    private static String Theo = "Theo";
    private static String Daley = "Daley";
    private static String Nicolas = "Nicolas";
    private static String Dmitri = "Dmitri";
    private static String Kruis = "Kruis";

    public SelectieController(JButton vermeer, JLabel vermeer1, JButton gregory, JButton toby, JButton jan,
            JButton vurnon, JButton eyong, JButton sulejmani, JButton cristian, JButton kolbeinn, JButton siem,
            JButton lorenzo, JButton andre, JButton nicolai, JButton theo, JButton daley, JButton nicolas,
            JButton dmitri, JButton kruis)

    {
        kruis = kruis;
        keeper = vermeer;
        verdediger1 = toby;
        verdediger = gregory;
        verdediger2 = jan;
        verdediger3 = vurnon;
        middenvelder = eyong;
        aanvaller = sulejmani;
        aanvaller1 = kolbeinn;
        middenvelder1 = cristian;
        imageLabel = vermeer1;
        middenvelder2 = siem;
        aanvaller2 = lorenzo;
        verdediger4 = andre;
        verdediger5 = nicolai;
        middenvelder3 = theo;
        verdediger6 = daley;
        middenvelder4 = nicolas;
        aanvaller3 = dmitri;

        //Kenneth Vermeer
         try
         {
             image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/kenneth.png"));

         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        }{

        // Gregory van der Wiel
        try
        {
        image1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/wiel.png"));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageIcon1 = new ImageIcon(image1);
        }{

        // Toby Alderweireld
        try
        {
        image2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/toby.png"));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageIcon2 = new ImageIcon(image2);
        }{

        // Jan Vertonghen
                try
                {
                image3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/jan.png"));

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imageIcon3 = new ImageIcon(image3);
                }{

        // Vurnon anita
        try
        {
        image4 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/vurnon.png"));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageIcon4 = new ImageIcon(image4);
        }{
            // Eyong Enoh
            try
            {
            image5 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/eyong.png"));

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageIcon5 = new ImageIcon(image5);
            }{
        // Miralem Sulejmani
                    try
                    {
                    image6 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/sulejmani.png"));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageIcon6 = new ImageIcon(image6);
                    }{
            // Cristian Eriksen
            try
            {
            image7 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/eriksen.png"));

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageIcon7 = new ImageIcon(image7);
            }{
                    // Kolbeinn sightorsson
                    try
                    {
                    image8 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/kolbeinn.png"));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageIcon8 = new ImageIcon(image8);
                    }{

            // Siem de Jong
            try
            {
            image9 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/siem.png"));

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageIcon9 = new ImageIcon(image9);
            }{
                    // Lorenzo Ebecilio
                    try
                    {
                    image10 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/lorenzo.png"));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageIcon10 = new ImageIcon(image10);
                    }{
                        // Andre Ooijer
                        try
                        {
                        image11 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/andre.png"));

                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        imageIcon11 = new ImageIcon(image11);
                        }{
                    // Nicolai Boilesen
                    try
                    {
                    image12 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/nicolai.png"));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageIcon12 = new ImageIcon(image12);
                    }{
                        // Theo Janssen
                        try
                        {
                        image13 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/theo.png"));

                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        imageIcon13 = new ImageIcon(image13);
                        }{
                    // Daley Blind
                    try
                    {
                    image14 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/daley.png"));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageIcon14 = new ImageIcon(image14);
                    }{
                        // Nicolas Lodeiro
                        try
                        {
                        image15 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/nicolas.png"));

                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        imageIcon15 = new ImageIcon(image15);
                        }{
                    // Dmitri Bulykin
                    try
                    {
                    image16 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/dmitri.png"));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    imageIcon16 = new ImageIcon(image16);
                    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
         String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
         // Kenneth Vermeer
         if (Vermeer.equals(actionCommand)) 
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {                       
                     imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon );
                     imageLabel.setBounds(75, 50, 120, 150);
                     kruis.setVisible(false);

                 }
             });
     }
         // Gregory van der Wiel
         if (Gregory.equals(actionCommand)) 
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {                       
                     imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon1 );
                     imageLabel.setBounds(75, 50, 120, 150);
                 }
             });
     }
         // Toby Alderweireld
         if (Alderweireld.equals(actionCommand)) 
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {                       
                     imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon2 );
                     imageLabel.setBounds(75, 50, 120, 150);
                 }
             });
     }
         // Jan Vertonghen
         if (Vertonghen.equals(actionCommand)) 
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {                       
                     imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon3 );
                     imageLabel.setBounds(75, 50, 120, 150);
                 }
             });
     }
         //Vurnon Anita
         if (Anita.equals(actionCommand)) 
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {                       
                     imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon4 );
                     imageLabel.setBounds(75, 50, 120, 150);
                 }
             });
     }
         // Eyong Enoh
         if (Enoh.equals(actionCommand)) 
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {                       
                     imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon5 );
                     imageLabel.setBounds(75, 50, 120, 150);
                 }
             });
     }
         // Miralem Sulejmani
         if (Sulejmani.equals(actionCommand)) 
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {                       
                     imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon6 );
                     imageLabel.setBounds(75, 50, 120, 150);
                 }
             });
         }
 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, whenever you have elements with names like button1, button2 etc. you need to refactor the code and work with an array instead. This way you can refer to the needed element using its index, instead of many if-else statements. That's applies for the `String`s , `Button`s, `Image`s and `ImageIcon`s.

Now, when a button is pressed, find it's index (in a loop for example) and make all other button/images disappear, using `setVisible(false)`, and only the relevant image display using `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: +1, for this nice info, moreover, to add the same properties to each and every `JButton` i.e. `setText(...)`, `setIcon()`, `setFont(...)`, `setCursor(...)` and `blah blah`, he can make a single function and pass each instance to that function to get the `JButton` with these added features. No need to write all the things again and again for each and every `JButton` :-)